# Instance variable of type list behaves as class variable

Tags: python, instance-variables, class-variables, canopy

In the following code, I thought `list` wouldbe a unique variable to each object constructed. Why is it shared as a class variable?

```
01 class Thing(object):
02     def __init__(self, my_list=[]): 
03         self.list = my_list 
04         return 
05 
06 thing1=Thing()
07 thing2=Thing()
08 thing1.list.append(1)
09 print thing2.list
```

`id(thing1)` is distinct from `id(things2)` but `id(thing1.list)` is the same as `id(thing2.list)`.

If I use `self.list = []` on line 3, the attribute is unique to each `Thing`.
If I use `thing1 = Thing(my_list=[])` on line 6, and similarly on line 7, then the attribute is unique to each `Thing`.

I am running Python 2.7 within the Canopy environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: You're changing `__init__()`'s mutable default argument. Make the default `None` and manually set it to `[]` in the method's body when that's its value.

Comment: This is [explained in the FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects).

Comment: Thanks all. Especially abarnert, as that FAQ (new to me) answers several other questions I had.

Comment: Having read the answers at "Least Astonishment", I think that it is better to leave the default as `my_list=[]` and then assign the instance variable to `self.list = my_list[:]` or `self.list = list(my_list)`. This has the advantage that the parameter type is explicitly stated.

Comment: Retracting above, using my_list[:] or another way to copy the argument is a bad idea if you ever might want to pass a list by reference instead of value. E.g. construct two objects that share a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing something like this:

```
01 class Thing(object):
02     def __init__(self, my_list=None):
03         if my_list is None:
04           my_list = []
04         self.list = my_list
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for an explanation as to why keyword arguments behave this way.

Comment: I think that it is better to leave the default as `my_list=[]` and then assign the instance variable to `self.list = my_list[:]` or `self.list = list(my_list)`. This way the parameter type is explicitly stated.

Comment: BBrown, you should only do that if you are sure you want a copied version of my_list. There may be cases where you actually want to use my_list but want to have the option to have it default to [].

Comment: Thanks terrapin. I understand, my suggestion to use my_list[:] would prevent the object from being able to change the list it was passed.